# How to implement a scrolling using ncurses?

Tags: c++, scroll, command-line-interface, ncurses

There are many questions about how to make a scrolling in ncurses, but I didn't found any clear answer on them. So, here is my case. I have two *WINDOW** objects that bisects the screen on two parts, like a split-screen. Now I'm implementing the part of my app which is like a file manager. The first window holds a files names and the second window holds the extensions of the files in current directory. I want to make it scrollable and I know, that I can achieve it with *pads*. The only clue, I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370377/scrolling-in-c-with-ncurses-pad). Here's my try using this approach:

```
WINDOW *win1, *win2;
int maxx, maxy, halfx;

getmaxyx(stdscr, maxy, maxx);
halfx = maxx >> 1;

win1 = newpad(maxy, halfx);
wprintw(win1, "File name: \n");
wrefresh(win1);

//don't pay much attention on this part of
//code, now it's just a window, then it will be pad too
win2 = newwin(maxy, halfx, 0, halfx);
wprintw(win2, "Extension: \n");
wrefresh(win2);

curs_set(0);//cursor off
int rowcount = 0;

//filling the windows with file data
for(directory_iterator beg(dir); beg != directory_iterator{}; ++beg)
{
    wprintw(win1, "%s\n", beg->path().stem().string().c_str());
    wrefresh(win1);
    wprintw(win2, "%s\n", beg->path().extension().string().c_str());
    wrefresh(win2);

    rowcount++;
}

//##############################
keypad(win1, TRUE);//SOLUTION
//##############################

int mypadpos = 0;
prefresh(win1, mypadpos, 0, 0, 0, maxy, maxx);

//spaghetti-code from the above question that I tried to adapt 
while ((ch = wgetch(win1)) != 'q')
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case KEY_UP:
            if (mypadpos >= 0)
                mypadpos--;

            prefresh(win1, mypadpos, 0, 0, 0, maxy, maxx);
            break;

        case KEY_DOWN:
            if (mypadpos <= rowcount+1)
                mypadpos++;

            prefresh(win1, mypadpos, 0, 0, 0, maxy-1, maxx);
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the last part of code doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the answer is easy. I forgot about the *keypad()* function. For those, who trying to make a scrolling in ncurses, this is the right solution.